# How to automatically convert csv to pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, csv

I have a problem with loading my csv file to pandas Dataframe. Problem is that csv has been converted from json files which contained nested json inside some records. After typically reading csv files with pd.read_csv, everything is a string, even these nested jsons (dictionaries). I'd like to have them as dicts, so I can then convert lets say two columns to dataframe. Here is example of the csv. I want "LoadNodes" and "LoadMembers" as dataframes with SubProjectId of the row.

Visual example of the pd:

```py
ProjectId   ModifiedBy  UpdatedOn   Nodes   Members Pipes   AirDucts    CableTrays  Objects3D   LoadNodes   LoadMembers LoadCases   LoadObject3Ds   GeometryObjects PipeRings   Results-Id  Results-Description Results-Name    Results-AppData-Version Results-AppData-Application Results-AppData-ApplicationVersion  Results-AppData-Name    Results-AppData-ModelClientId   Results-AppData-GlobalOrientation   Results-Statistics-DurationTime Results-Statistics-LoadingDataDuration  Results-Statistics-CalculationDuration  Results-Statistics-LoadingResultsDuration   Results-Statistics-IsCalculated Results-Statistics-AreExceptions    Results-Statistics-CalculatorVersion    Results-Combination Results-UlsResults  Results-SlsResults  Results-Exceptions  Results-Utilization Results-Spacing Results-Buckling    Results-LoadCases   Results
SubProjectId                                                                                                                                                                
32212   10949   antonio_melicano@cameco.com 2021-04-22T23:02:18.073 [{'Id': 1, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Node ...   [{'Id': 1, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Bar 1...   []  []  []  []  []  [{'Id': 1, 'Description': '', 'Name': 'Point',...   [{'Id': 255, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Liv...   NaN [{'Id': 7404, 'Description': None, 'Name': Non...   []  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

link to csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IyONYdnIS44avtxXMLZN7ju8r1i2bq7r/view?usp=sharing

Have you got idea how to make it?

Here are the header line and the first data line of the csv file:

```
,ProjectId,SubProjectId,ModifiedBy,UpdatedOn,Nodes,Members,Pipes,AirDucts,CableTrays,Objects3D,LoadNodes,LoadMembers,LoadCases,LoadObject3Ds,GeometryObjects,PipeRings,Results-Id,Results-Description,Results-Name,Results-AppData-Version,Results-AppData-Application,Results-AppData-ApplicationVersion,Results-AppData-Name,Results-AppData-ModelClientId,Results-AppData-GlobalOrientation,Results-Statistics-DurationTime,Results-Statistics-LoadingDataDuration,Results-Statistics-CalculationDuration,Results-Statistics-LoadingResultsDuration,Results-Statistics-IsCalculated,Results-Statistics-AreExceptions,Results-Statistics-CalculatorVersion,Results-Combination,Results-UlsResults,Results-SlsResults,Results-Exceptions,Results-Utilization,Results-Spacing,Results-Buckling,Results-LoadCases,Results
0,10949,32212,antonio_melicano@cameco.com,2021-04-22T23:02:18.073,"[{'Id': 1, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Node 1', 'No': 1, 'Position': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.56283}, 'MemberIds': [1], 'Details': {'SelectedId': 339738627, 'ConnectorId': 547, 'ConnectorVariantId': 2099, 'AnchorId': None, 'AnchorVariantId': None, 'BuildingMaterialId': 1, 'Rotation': 0.0, 'IsHinge': False, 'IsAutoGenerated': False, 'PushButtonId': None, 'UserSelection': False, 'IsBracket': False, 'NodeOffset': {'X': 1.407575607292877e-06, 'Y': -1.1102230246251565e-16, 'Z': 0.06904959771156305}, 'ArmDetails': [{'ArmId': 1, 'RowHoleId': -1}], 'Connectors': [{'Id': 547, 'Name': 'MT-B-GXL S3 OC', 'VariantId': 2099, 'ArticleNumber': 2272108, 'VariantName': 'MT-B-GXL S3 OC (C_SW_MT-90_web)', 'IsBase': True, 'ArmDetails': [{'Id': 1, 'MemberId': 1, 'BorderBeam': True, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': 1, 'ConnectorId': 547, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}], 'Transformation': None, 'SelectedId': 339738627, 'Anchor': None, 'LogicVerifications': [], 'Weight': 0.0}], 'FasteningMethod': 0, 'BeamClampingType': 5}, 'NodeSupportId': 1, 'GeometryObjectId': 7405, 'Type': 0, 'Members': [], 'NodeVirtuals': [], 'PipeRing': None}, {'Id': 2, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Node 2', 'No': 2, 'Position': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}, 'MemberIds': [1, 2], 'Details': {'SelectedId': -233701373, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorVariantId': 2063, 'AnchorId': None, 'AnchorVariantId': None, 'BuildingMaterialId': 2, 'Rotation': 0.0, 'IsHinge': False, 'IsAutoGenerated': False, 'PushButtonId': None, 'UserSelection': False, 'IsBracket': False, 'NodeOffset': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'ArmDetails': [], 'Connectors': [{'Id': 388, 'Name': 'MT-C-GLP T OC', 'VariantId': 2063, 'ArticleNumber': 2272075, 'VariantName': 'MT-C-GLP T OC (C_D)', 'IsBase': False, 'ArmDetails': [{'Id': 1, 'MemberId': 1, 'BorderBeam': False, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': None, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}, {'Id': 2, 'MemberId': 2, 'BorderBeam': True, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': None, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}], 'Transformation': None, 'SelectedId': -233701373, 'Anchor': None, 'LogicVerifications': [], 'Weight': 0.0}], 'FasteningMethod': 0, 'BeamClampingType': None}, 'NodeSupportId': None, 'GeometryObjectId': None, 'Type': 0, 'Members': [], 'NodeVirtuals': [], 'PipeRing': None}, {'Id': 4, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Node 4', 'No': 3, 'Position': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}, 'MemberIds': [2, 3], 'Details': {'SelectedId': 907149315, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorVariantId': 2063, 'AnchorId': None, 'AnchorVariantId': None, 'BuildingMaterialId': 2, 'Rotation': 0.0, 'IsHinge': False, 'IsAutoGenerated': False, 'PushButtonId': None, 'UserSelection': False, 'IsBracket': False, 'NodeOffset': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'ArmDetails': [], 'Connectors': [{'Id': 388, 'Name': 'MT-C-GLP T OC', 'VariantId': 2063, 'ArticleNumber': 2272075, 'VariantName': 'MT-C-GLP T OC (C_D)', 'IsBase': False, 'ArmDetails': [{'Id': 1, 'MemberId': 2, 'BorderBeam': False, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': None, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}, {'Id': 2, 'MemberId': 3, 'BorderBeam': True, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': None, 'ConnectorId': 388, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}], 'Transformation': None, 'SelectedId': 907149315, 'Anchor': None, 'LogicVerifications': [], 'Weight': 0.0}], 'FasteningMethod': 0, 'BeamClampingType': None}, 'NodeSupportId': None, 'GeometryObjectId': None, 'Type': 0, 'Members': [], 'NodeVirtuals': [], 'PipeRing': None}, {'Id': 9, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Node 9', 'No': 4, 'Position': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.8}, 'MemberIds': [3], 'Details': {'SelectedId': -1602224125, 'ConnectorId': 486, 'ConnectorVariantId': 1926, 'AnchorId': 146, 'AnchorVariantId': 95, 'BuildingMaterialId': 2, 'Rotation': 0.0, 'IsHinge': True, 'IsAutoGenerated': False, 'PushButtonId': None, 'UserSelection': True, 'IsBracket': False, 'NodeOffset': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'ArmDetails': [{'ArmId': 1, 'RowHoleId': -1}], 'Connectors': [{'Id': 486, 'Name': 'MT-C-GL OC', 'VariantId': 1926, 'ArticleNumber': 2272066, 'VariantName': 'MT-C-GL OC (C_2)', 'IsBase': True, 'ArmDetails': [{'Id': 1, 'MemberId': 3, 'BorderBeam': True, 'Dimension': 0.0, 'Resistances': None, 'ReleaseId': 0, 'ReleaseAlternativeId': 1, 'ConnectorId': 486, 'ConnectorName': None, 'Transformation': None, 'OffsetModels': None}], 'Transformation': None, 'SelectedId': -1602224125, 'Anchor': None, 'LogicVerifications': [], 'Weight': 0.0}], 'FasteningMethod': 1, 'BeamClampingType': None}, 'NodeSupportId': 1, 'GeometryObjectId': 7404, 'Type': 0, 'Members': [], 'NodeVirtuals': [], 'PipeRing': None}]","[{'Id': 1, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Bar 1', 'No': 1, 'Gamma': 0.0, 'NodeStartId': 1, 'NodeEndId': 2, 'CrossSectionId': 405, 'Details': {'HasSupport': False, 'BuildingMaterialId': 0, 'Type': None, 'AnchorLocation': '', 'Distance': 0.0, 'IsBracket': False, 'HingedStart': {'IsHinged': False, 'Code': 2}, 'HingedEnd': {'IsHinged': False, 'Code': 0}, 'CrossOverDir': None, 'ChannelSupportSingle': False, 'MediaInterface': {'IsActive': False, 'MemberId': 0, 'StartingOffset': 0.0, 'Length': 0.0, 'Details': {'RowHoleId': None, 'Normal': None, 'SelectedId': None, 'ConnectorId': None, 'ConnectorVariantId': None, 'Connectors': []}}, 'Static': {'IsStatic': False, 'NodeId': None}, 'IsSeismicArm': False}, 'NodeIds': [], 'DivisionId': None, 'ReleaseStartId': None, 'ReleaseEndId': None, 'EccentricityId': None, 'Type': 0, 'Buckling': {'IsActivate': True, 'BucklingLengthCoeffY': 2.0, 'BucklingLengthCoeffZ': 2.0, 'LtbLengthCoeff': 2.0}, 'NonLinearId': None, 'Nodes': [], 'Length': 0.0}, {'Id': 2, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Bar 2', 'No': 2, 'Gamma': 0.0, 'NodeStartId': 2, 'NodeEndId': 4, 'CrossSectionId': 405, 'Details': {'HasSupport': False, 'BuildingMaterialId': 0, 'Type': None, 'AnchorLocation': '', 'Distance': 0.0, 'IsBracket': False, 'HingedStart': {'IsHinged': False, 'Code': 0}, 'HingedEnd': {'IsHinged': False, 'Code': 0}, 'CrossOverDir': None, 'ChannelSupportSingle': False, 'MediaInterface': {'IsActive': False, 'MemberId': 0, 'StartingOffset': 0.0, 'Length': 0.0, 'Details': {'RowHoleId': None, 'Normal': None, 'SelectedId': None, 'ConnectorId': None, 'ConnectorVariantId': None, 'Connectors': []}}, 'Static': {'IsStatic': False, 'NodeId': None}, 'IsSeismicArm': False}, 'NodeIds': [], 'DivisionId': None, 'ReleaseStartId': None, 'ReleaseEndId': None, 'EccentricityId': None, 'Type': 0, 'Buckling': {'IsActivate': True, 'BucklingLengthCoeffY': 2.0, 'BucklingLengthCoeffZ': 2.0, 'LtbLengthCoeff': 2.0}, 'NonLinearId': None, 'Nodes': [], 'Length': 0.0}, {'Id': 3, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Bar 3', 'No': 3, 'Gamma': 0.0, 'NodeStartId': 4, 'NodeEndId': 9, 'CrossSectionId': 405, 'Details': {'HasSupport': False, 'BuildingMaterialId': 0, 'Type': None, 'AnchorLocation': '', 'Distance': 0.0, 'IsBracket': False, 'HingedStart': {'IsHinged': False, 'Code': 0}, 'HingedEnd': {'IsHinged': True, 'Code': 2}, 'CrossOverDir': None, 'ChannelSupportSingle': False, 'MediaInterface': {'IsActive': False, 'MemberId': 0, 'StartingOffset': 0.0, 'Length': 0.0, 'Details': {'RowHoleId': None, 'Normal': None, 'SelectedId': None, 'ConnectorId': None, 'ConnectorVariantId': None, 'Connectors': []}}, 'Static': {'IsStatic': False, 'NodeId': None}, 'IsSeismicArm': False}, 'NodeIds': [], 'DivisionId': None, 'ReleaseStartId': None, 'ReleaseEndId': 1, 'EccentricityId': None, 'Type': 0, 'Buckling': {'IsActivate': True, 'BucklingLengthCoeffY': 2.0, 'BucklingLengthCoeffZ': 2.0, 'LtbLengthCoeff': 2.0}, 'NonLinearId': None, 'Nodes': [], 'Length': 0.0}]",[],[],[],[],[],"[{'Id': 1, 'Description': '', 'Name': 'Point', 'No': 0, 'LoadCaseId': 255, 'Rotation': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'LTBSupport': False, 'IsConcetrated': True, 'IsRelative': False, 'Points': [{'Forces': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -10000.0}, 'Moments': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'Position': 0.8121197179978898}], 'MemberIds': [2], 'IsGlobal': True, 'IsProjected': False, 'Type': 'BarForce', 'DefinitionType': 0, 'Details': {'IsMirrored': False, 'MirroredLoadId': None}, 'SeismicLoad': None, 'Members': []}, {'Id': 2, 'Description': '', 'Name': 'Point (1)', 'No': 0, 'LoadCaseId': 261, 'Rotation': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'LTBSupport': False, 'IsConcetrated': False, 'IsRelative': False, 'Points': [{'Forces': {'X': 1000.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Moments': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Position': 0.70616}, {'Forces': {'X': 1000.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Moments': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Position': 1.4}], 'MemberIds': [3], 'IsGlobal': True, 'IsProjected': False, 'Type': 'BarForce', 'DefinitionType': 0, 'Details': {'IsMirrored': True, 'MirroredLoadId': 3}, 'SeismicLoad': None, 'Members': []}, {'Id': 3, 'Description': '', 'Name': 'Point (1) (1)', 'No': 0, 'LoadCaseId': 262, 'Rotation': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'LTBSupport': False, 'IsConcetrated': False, 'IsRelative': False, 'Points': [{'Forces': {'X': -1000.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Moments': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Position': 0.70616}, {'Forces': {'X': -1000.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Moments': {'X': -0.0, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': -0.0}, 'Position': 1.4}], 'MemberIds': [3], 'IsGlobal': True, 'IsProjected': False, 'Type': 'BarForce', 'DefinitionType': 0, 'Details': {'IsMirrored': True, 'MirroredLoadId': 2}, 'SeismicLoad': None, 'Members': []}]","[{'Id': 255, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Live ', 'DesignBasisId': 2, 'LoadCombinationBasisId': 19, 'LoadActionId': 83, 'No': 5, 'DeadWeightDirection': None, 'LoadCaseType': 4, 'LoadActionType': 1, 'AnalysisType': 0, 'LeadingVariableAction': None, 'LifeFactor': 0.0, 'IsConvertedToSeismic': True, 'IsMirrored': False, 'MirroredWithLoadCaseId': None, 'SeismicLoadCase': None, 'MappingCode': None}, {'Id': 261, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Seismic (+x)', 'DesignBasisId': 2, 'LoadCombinationBasisId': 19, 'LoadActionId': 86, 'No': 13, 'DeadWeightDirection': None, 'LoadCaseType': 4, 'LoadActionType': 2, 'AnalysisType': 0, 'LeadingVariableAction': None, 'LifeFactor': 0.0, 'IsConvertedToSeismic': False, 'IsMirrored': True, 'MirroredWithLoadCaseId': 262, 'SeismicLoadCase': '+X', 'MappingCode': None}, {'Id': 262, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Seismic (-x)', 'DesignBasisId': 2, 'LoadCombinationBasisId': 19, 'LoadActionId': 86, 'No': 14, 'DeadWeightDirection': None, 'LoadCaseType': 4, 'LoadActionType': 2, 'AnalysisType': 0, 'LeadingVariableAction': None, 'LifeFactor': 0.0, 'IsConvertedToSeismic': False, 'IsMirrored': True, 'MirroredWithLoadCaseId': 261, 'SeismicLoadCase': '-X', 'MappingCode': None}, {'Id': 251, 'Description': None, 'Name': 'Self Weight Support', 'DesignBasisId': 2, 'LoadCombinationBasisId': 19, 'LoadActionId': 82, 'No': 1, 'DeadWeightDirection': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -1.0}, 'LoadCaseType': 0, 'LoadActionType': 0, 'AnalysisType': 0, 'LeadingVariableAction': None, 'LifeFactor': 0.0, 'IsConvertedToSeismic': True, 'IsMirrored': False, 'MirroredWithLoadCaseId': None, 'SeismicLoadCase': None, 'MappingCode': None}]",,"[{'Id': 7404, 'Description': None, 'Name': None, 'Min': {'X': 0.89756, 'Y': -0.25, 'Z': 0.8}, 'Max': {'X': 1.39756, 'Y': 0.25, 'Z': 1.0}, 'ElementType': 'Ceiling', 'BuildingMaterialId': 2, 'BoundBox': {'Min': {'X': 0.89756, 'Y': -0.25, 'Z': 0.8}, 'Max': {'X': 1.39756, 'Y': 0.25, 'Z': 1.0}, 'Size': {'X': 0.4999999999999999, 'Y': 0.5, 'Z': 0.19999999999999996}, 'MidPoint': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.9}}, 'Direction': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 1.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'Steel': None, 'Concrete': {'DrillingDepth': 0.15, 'Grade': 'C20/25', 'Thickness': 0.2}}, {'Id': 7405, 'Description': None, 'Name': None, 'Min': {'X': -0.6193, 'Y': -0.25, 'Z': 0.56283}, 'Max': {'X': -0.3526, 'Y': 0.25, 'Z': 0.70883}, 'ElementType': 'SteelElement', 'BuildingMaterialId': 1, 'BoundBox': {'Min': {'X': -0.6193, 'Y': -0.25, 'Z': 0.56283}, 'Max': {'X': -0.3526, 'Y': 0.25, 'Z': 0.70883}, 'Size': {'X': 0.26669999999999994, 'Y': 0.5, 'Z': 0.1459999999999999}, 'MidPoint': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.63583}}, 'Direction': {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 1.0, 'Z': 0.0}, 'Steel': {'SteelShapeId': 1721, 'Rotation': 1.5707963267948966, 'IsCustom': False, 'Parameters': {'ShapeCode': 'H', 'H': 0.2667, 'B': 0.146, 'Tfl': 0.0127, 'Tw': 0.0079, 'R': 0.0159, 'MateriaId': 22}}, 'Concrete': None}]",[],,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: First, we do not need a link to a huge csv file, but you should put a few lines **as text** in the question itself so that we can easily try and load the file (I have done that part for you). But you real problem is that this csv file is just junk. If you initialy had json files, you should do the processing *before* building the csv file. It can be done after, but it would certainly be both more easy and robust to do it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the string representation of a dictionary as a dictionary with a custom converter:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', converters={'LoadNodes': pd.eval,'LoadMembers': pd.eval})
```